# recursive pthread spawning - stack location

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm playing around with `pthreads`, now it seems to me, that when i call `pthread_create` from a thread that was previously spawned with `pthread_create`, the stack for the new `pthread` will be allocated on the stack of the father thread. In the main-thread, this would not be a problem, because the main thread's stack can still grow, as the MMU will allocate and map new memory for it when neccessary, but a `pthread` has a fixed stacksize. So when i create a pthread from a pthread, I have to make sure that the father-pthread's stacksize (and guardsize) is large enough to hold the child pthread's stack (plus guardpages).
Is that assumption correct? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Comment: _'now it seems to me'_ How do you approve such observation? What's going to lead you to such assumption?

Comment: You are way off-base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parent-thread created using `pthread_create()` may create another child-thread using `pthread_create()`.

If the the child's stack would live on the parent's stack then the child's stack would become invalid as soon as the parent ends, and the child couldn't live on.

The latter is not the case.

From this one can conclude the child's stack does **not** live on the parent's stack.

Comment: you're right. after some more testing, i can conclude that my assumption was incorrect. thx for the answer